# icu tokenizer in node.js 12

Tags: node.js, v8, icu

I have a ICU tokenizer for Python3. [This](https://github.com/loretoparisi/python-icu) python code uses `BreakIterator` and `Locale` from icu (PyICU) library:

```
from icu import Locale,BreakIterator
def wordSegmenter(txt, iter):
    tokens = []
    bi.setText(txt)
    start = iter.first()
    try:
        while True:
            end = next(iter)
            tokens.append(txt[start:end])
            start = end
    except StopIteration:
        pass
    return tokens

text = u'退屈であくびばっかしていた毎日'
tokens = wordSegmenter(text, wordBreakIterator("ja"))
['退屈', 'で', 'あくび', 'ばっか', 'し', 'てい', 'た', '毎日']
```

I have now to port ICU to to NodeJS via node-gyp bindings. When building the native library [here](https://github.com/loretoparisi/node-icu) I get the error

```
../src/wordsplit.cc:82:65: error: too few arguments to function call, single argument 'context' was
      not specified
            Nan::New<FunctionTemplate>(SplitWords)->GetFunction());
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^
/Users/loretoparisi/Library/Caches/node-gyp/12.13.1/include/node/v8.h:5995:3: note: 'GetFunction'
```

that [seems](https://github.com/nodejs/node-addon-examples/issues/94) to be related to `Nan` support and `Node12.x`. How to correctly correctly port to Node12 and get rid of V8 deprecations?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as the error message tells you, `FunctionTemplate::GetFunction` now needs a Context. I don't know much about Nan, but I'd suggest to try `Nan::GetCurrentContext()`.

That said, if you run Node 12 with `--harmony-intl-segmenter`, you get access to V8's supposedly complete (but not yet shipping by default) implementation of the JavaScript `Intl.Segmenter` proposal (https://github.com/tc39/proposal-intl-segmenter), which is also based on ICU. That might save you a bunch of work, *and* it's on the way towards becoming an official part of JavaScript, so it will soon be widely available.

Comment: Thank you. I was aware of the Intl.v8BreakIterator, but it seems there are still issues in Node 13, where it is integrated by defaults. Since node13 (that brings ICU to nodejs finally!)  is not going to become LTS, we will have to wait a bit to get this working...